# Conversion of date format in CSV file

Tags: excel, azure-data-factory

Hi I have to load data from an Excel file to Azure data ware house, but during the conversion I had a problem converting the date formats in my excel file.

The date format in the Excel file is `Tue Feb 01 09:02:39 IST 2000`, but I need it in `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Can anyone help? I tried to change the date format while connecting the source, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen a date like that ( with the IST etc ) and I am forced to believe that at this time it is stored as string and not datetime .

Anyways since you are using excel you transform into different columns and then recreate the date field . The information like days and month can be stripped of as if you have the proper date , SQL have function which can be used to get these back .

You can transform to date by navigating to Excel ->Data -> Text to Columns.